# How to measure blender camera Dynamic range

Tags: camera, lighting, measurement

I watched many youtube videos about Filmic, but in blender 3.0 it is a little bit different.

Are those videos outdated or I get them wrong??

My testing is a grid and double up the light watt each grid

[image]

Output format: OpenEXR full float

Reopening of the exr file in Davinci resolve HDR color management, it show the file store 65 stop of light
[image]

Comment: Your calculations will be off. Along achromatic, the maximum value in the working tristimulus model will be `2*6.5 * 0.18`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenEXR format stores original linear color, without Filmic or any color management.

> For intermediate files in production, it is recommended to use OpenEXR
> files. These are always stored in scene linear color spaces, without
> any data loss. That makes them suitable to store renders that can
> later be composited, color graded and converted to different output
> formats.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it dynamic range with 32 bit EXR format is for all practical purposes unlimited. 32 bit float values can range from 1.175494×10<sup>-38</sup> to 3.4028237×10<sup>38</sup>. Precision, however, is not unlimited so it should be possible to reach some limits when editing extremely high dynamic range images, but it's really high and should be enough for anything one can think of. The way I see it - if this is a concern, you are probably doing something very wrong in the first place.